# Error while creating first project with ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

Hi i try to create my first app in ionic and i get this error :

```
f:\>ionic start bletry3
 ? What starter would you like to use: blank
 ✔ Creating directory .\bletry3 - done!
  [INFO] Fetching app base (https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic2-app-
    base/archive/master.tar.gz)
       ✔ Downloading - done!
     [INFO] Fetching starter template blank (https://github.com/ionic-
  team/ionic2-starter-blank/archive/master.tar.gz)
✔ Downloading - done!
✔ Updating package.json with app details - done!
✔ Creating configuration file ionic.config.json - done!
[INFO] Installing dependencies may take several minutes!
> npm install
✖ Running command - failed!
[ERROR] An error occurred while running npm install (exit code 1):

       npm WARN deprecated object-keys@0.2.0: Please update to the latest 
  object-keys
    npm WARN prefer global node-gyp@3.6.2 should be installed with -g

    > node-sass@4.5.0 install f:\bletry3\node_modules\node-sass
    > node scripts/install.js

    Downloading binary from
    https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.5.0/win32-x64-57_binding.node
    Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.5.0/win32-x64-57_binding.node":

    HTTP error 404 Not Found

    Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
    try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g.

    export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234

    or configure npm proxy via

    npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080

    > fsevents@1.1.2 install f:\bletry3\node_modules\fsevents
    > node install


    > node-sass@4.5.0 postinstall f:\bletry3\node_modules\node-sass
    > node scripts/build.js

    Building: D:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe f:\bletry3\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild
    --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
    gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
    gyp verb cli [ 'D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
    gyp verb cli   'f:\\bletry3\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
    gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
    gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
    gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
    gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
    gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
    gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library=' ]
    gyp info using node-gyp@3.6.2
    gyp info using node@8.0.0 | win32 | x64
    gyp verb command rebuild []
    gyp verb command clean []
    gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
    gyp verb command configure []
    gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
    gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
    gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (f:\bletry3\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at F (f:\bletry3\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at E (f:\bletry3\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at f:\bletry3\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
    gyp verb `which` failed     at f:\bletry3\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
    gyp verb `which` failed     at f:\bletry3\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
    gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
    gyp verb `which` failed  python2 { Error: not found: python2
    gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (f:\bletry3\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at F (f:\bletry3\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at E (f:\bletry3\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at f:\bletry3\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
    gyp verb `which` failed     at f:\bletry3\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
    gyp verb `which` failed     at f:\bletry3\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
    gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21) code: 'ENOENT' }
    gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
    gyp verb `which` succeeded python C:\Python27\python.EXE
    gyp verb check python version `C:\Python27\python.EXE -c "import platform;
    print(platform.python_version());"` returned: "2.7.13\r\n"
    gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 8.0.0
    gyp verb command install [ '8.0.0' ]
    gyp verb install input version string "8.0.0"
    gyp verb install installing version: 8.0.0
    gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
    gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
    gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
    gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
    gyp verb install version is good
    gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 8.0.0
    gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: f:\bletry3\node_modules\node-sass\build
    gyp verb build dir "build" dir needed to be created? f:\bletry3\node_modules\node-sass\build
    gyp verb Not using VS2017: Could not use PowerShell to find VS2017
    gyp verb build/config.gypi creating config file
    gyp verb build/config.gypi writing out config file: f:\bletry3\node_modules\node-sass\build\config.gypi
    gyp verb config.gypi checking for gypi file: f:\bletry3\node_modules\node-sass\config.gypi
    gyp verb common.gypi checking for gypi file: f:\bletry3\node_modules\node-sass\common.gypi
    gyp verb gyp gyp format was not specified; forcing "msvs"
    gyp info spawn C:\Python27\python.EXE
    gyp info spawn args [ 'f:\\bletry3\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
    gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
    gyp info spawn args   '-f',
    gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
    gyp info spawn args   '-G',
    gyp info spawn args   'msvs_version=auto',
    gyp info spawn args   '-I',
    gyp info spawn args   'f:\\bletry3\\node_modules\\node-sass\\build\\config.gypi',
    gyp info spawn args   '-I',
    gyp info spawn args   'f:\\bletry3\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
    gyp info spawn args   '-I',
    gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\MBehtemam\\.node-gyp\\8.0.0\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
    gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
    gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
    gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\MBehtemam\\.node-gyp\\8.0.0',
    gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=f:\\bletry3\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
    gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\Users\\MBehtemam\\.node-gyp\\8.0.0\\<(target_arch)\\node.lib',
    gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=f:\\bletry3\\node_modules\\node-sass',
    gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
    gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
    gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
    gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
    gyp info spawn args   'f:\\bletry3\\node_modules\\node-sass\\build',
    gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
    gyp verb command build []
    gyp verb build type Release
    gyp verb architecture x64
    gyp verb node dev dir C:\Users\MBehtemam\.node-gyp\8.0.0
    gyp verb found first Solution file build/binding.sln
    gyp verb could not find "msbuild.exe" in PATH - finding location in registry
    gyp info spawn C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
    gyp info spawn args [ 'build/binding.sln',
    gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
    gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64' ]
    Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
    Build started 6/16/2017 2:02:34 PM.
    Project "f:\bletry3\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
    ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
    Building solution configuration "Release|x64".
    MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe". To fix this, 1) install the
    .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to
    the system path if it is installed elsewhere.  [f:\bletry3\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.sln]
    Done Building Project "f:\bletry3\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.sln" (default targets) -- FAILED.

    Build FAILED.

    "f:\bletry3\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.sln" (default target) (1) ->
    (_src_\libsass target) ->
    MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe". To fix this, 1) install the
    .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to
    the system path if it is installed elsewhere.  [f:\bletry3\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.sln]

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

    Time Elapsed 00:00:01.20
    gyp ERR! build error
    gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (f:\bletry3\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:258:23)
    gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
    gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:197:12)
    gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.15063
    gyp ERR! command "D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe"
    "f:\\bletry3\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext="
    "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
    gyp ERR! cwd f:\bletry3\node_modules\node-sass
    gyp ERR! node -v v8.0.0
    gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
    gyp ERR! not ok
    Build failed with error code: 1
    npm WARN Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir
    'f:\bletry3\node_modules\are-we-there-yet\node_modules'
    npm WARN  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir
    'f:\bletry3\node_modules\are-we-there-yet\node_modules'
    npm WARN   errno: -4048,
    npm WARN   code: 'EPERM',
    npm WARN   syscall: 'scandir',
    npm WARN   path: 'f:\\bletry3\\node_modules\\are-we-there-yet\\node_modules' }
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! node-sass@4.5.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.5.0 postinstall script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\MBehtemam\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-06-16T09_32_39_772Z-debug.log
```

```

and my ionic info is :

```
         f:\try>ionic info
         [WARN] You are not in an Ionic project directory. Project context may be missing.

global packages:

```
@ionic/cli-utils : 1.4.0
Ionic CLI        : 3.4.0
```

System:

````
Node       : v8.0.0
OS         : Windows 10
Xcode      : not installed
ios-deploy : not installed
ios-sim    : not installed
npm        : 5.0.0```
````

Comment: instead of `ionic start bletry3` try this `ionic start bletry3 blank`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem is that ionic is not ready for npm version 5 ,so i uninstall Node version 8 and install Node version 6 LTS and everything work well .

Comment: Glad to hear that you solved the issue. Please mark this as the accepted answer so we can close the issue :)

Comment: @sebaferreras  ok but it say i can accepted after 2 days